# How can I set style JUST for third child of tr

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table, in tr I have 7 th in it. I want to set `display: none` for the third child of tr and just for that one!

How can I set this style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**:nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector with constant expression as a param to hide both `td` and `th` in the third column:

```
td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r5dq54b4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, you can do something like this:

`$('tr').find('td:eq(3)').hide();`

Or, with css you can do:

`tr > td:nth-child(3) {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nth-of-type` CSS selector to just stylize just the third `tr` element of a table element `td` of ID `#table`, like so:

```
#table > tr:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr style="display:none;">
```